# Two different Stokes' theorems

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, stokes-theorem

There are two different Stokes' theorems. One is used typically in analysis and can be stated as follows:  for each $u\in C^1(\bar{U})$ ,with $U\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ with boundary $C^1$,and $U$ bounded we have
$$\int_{U} \operatorname{div} \mathbf{u}\, d x=\int_{\partial U} \mathbf{u} \cdot \nu \,d S$$
where $\nu$ takes the outer normal direction of $U$.

Another Stokes' theorem typically appears in differential geometry and says

let $M$ be an oriented smooth $n$-manifold with boundary, and let $\omega$ be a compactly supported smooth $(n-1)$-form on $M$. Then
$$
\int_{M} d \omega=\int_{\partial M} \omega
$$

Here are some questions about them:

1. when we consider $U\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ as manifold,there is no notion of manifold boundary if $U$ is open, why we can consider the "boundary" here?
2. the second theorem needs compact supported condition, whereas the first one does not need.  What's the difference between them?
3. Can we remove the bounded condition for $U$ in theorem 1?

Comment: If we assume $u$ in case one be compacted supported,then if taking $U$ open,without boundary will coinside with the second Stokes' theorem.

Comment: I guess the first formula means $\int_{\bar{U}} \operatorname{div} \mathbf{u}\, d x=\int_{\partial \bar{U}} \mathbf{u} \cdot \nu \,d S
$ while boundary has measure zero in terms in measure $dx$ we typically written the integral in $U$

Comment: In my opinion in the first case $\partial U$ is the boundary of $U$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, not as a manifold. And if you remove the boundedness of $U$ then the theorem doesn't hold. Take on $U = \{(x,y)| x \ge 0\} \subset \mathbb R^2$ the vector field $\vec u = (x,0)$ then at the boundaries $\vec u$ vanishes and so the RHS, while the LHS is infinite

Comment: Yeah,I think so,it's just notation convention,nothing more than that @Physor

Comment: ...and that is why the second needs a compact support condition, while in the first it is included since one "adds" the boundries of a bounded subset to the set so it becomes compact and the "vector" field becomes compactly supported. I hope some one checks my comments if they are answering the point, I'm not expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To apply Stokes, you cannot just have an $\omega$ that's defined only over $U$, instead $\omega$ has to be extended to $\partial U$ (at least $C^1$-ly), so the boundary is implicitly there. In practice, when we integrate an explicitly expressed function, it's usually defined almost everywhere. For example, integerate div $\textbf{u}$ on the open unit ball where $\textbf{u} = (x, y, z)$. We can instead integrate $\textbf{u}$ on the unit sphere. Here we are implicitly using the fact that the vector field $\textbf{u}$ can be extended to the sphere by the same formula.
2. Compactly supported is not the best condition, but some condition to make the integrals finite is necessary. The first version can be false if no such condition is posed. In calculus, we usually only apply Stokes when $\overline{U}$ is bounded, therefore compact. If we remove the boundedness, we have to then assume something like $\omega$ has compact support like in the second version, which is a weaker condition than $\overline{U}$ is bounded.

Comment: 1.thank you the extenable condition is used to guarantee the integral finite(well defined correct?

Comment: I don't know whether this is true. For example, even over $\mathbb R^1$, we can have a function $f(x)$ defined over $(a,b)$ with $f'(x)$ defined almost everywhere, but the fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't hold. This is not a valid counter-example, as $f(x)$ won't be $C^1$. There might ways to explore the weakness by controlling the integral without controlling the behavior of going to infinity/boundary, as we often see in analysis.

Comment: Let $f(x) = \sqrt{u}$, then over $(0, 1)$, the integral $\int_0^1 f'(x)dx$ is finite. And the fundamental theorem holds, but at least $f(x)$ is not $C^1$ at $0$, though the continuous extension still exists. We cannot get any worse in dimension 1. Anyway, these have very little to do with practice.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. when we consider $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ as manifold,there is no notion of manifold boundary if $U$ is open, why we can consider the "boundary" here?

A "manifold with boundary" is not a particular type of manifold, it's a generalization. Instead of a set where every point has a neighborhood diffeomorphic to a ball $\{x:|x|<1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, a manifold with boundary is a set where every point has a neighborhood diffeomorphic either to a ball $\{x:|x|<1\}$ or to a half-ball $\{x:|x|<1 \land \langle x, e_1 \rangle \geq 0\}$. So a manifold in the usual sense can be considered a "manifold with boundary" which has the empty set as boundary. (This implies that every exact differential form $d \omega$ on a manifold $M$ has $\int_M d \omega = \int_{\emptyset} \omega = 0$.)

> 2. the second theorem needs compact supported condition, whereas the first one does not need. What's the difference between them?

Your first stated theorem is the special case of the second version where $\omega$ is a $1$-form and $M \subset \mathbb{R^n}$.

A vector field on $U \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is essentially a function ${\mathbf u}: U \to \mathbb{R^n}$. We associate this $\mathbf u$ with the $1$-form $\omega: U \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$\omega(x)(v) = \langle{\mathbf u}(x), v\rangle$$
Then it will work out that $d \omega = \mathrm{div}\, {\mathbf u}\, dx$ and $\int_{\partial U} \omega = \int_{\partial U} {\mathbf u} \cdot v\, dS$.

The conditions for the two versions are exactly the same, given that the first statement makes the domain $U$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology and metric, a set is compact if and only if the set is both closed and bounded. The second version doesn't require that the manifold is embedded in any particular $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, but since the first version is in the context of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it can restate "compact support" as the more familiar terms "closed" and "bounded".

Comment: Oh ,You misunderstood the first question,I know that for open subset $U$ ,$\partial U = \emptyset$,what I mean is then the integral is constant 0 since RHS is zero.

Comment: Yes, if we're talking about a manifold, then there is no boundary. A "manifold with boundary" is something else which is usually not a manifold.